# How to access a list from other class in python -- AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'lst1'

Tags: python

I want to access a list from Class A in Class B

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lst1 = [1,2,3]

class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lst2 = A.lst1
  
  def printLst(self):
    print(self.lst2)

b = B()

b.printLst()
```

I want to show that
b.printLst() -- [1,2,3]

What I get now:

```
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'lst1'
```

Many thanks

Comment: Read more about the difference between classes and instances

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are confusing a static attribute with an object attribute. When you define the list on the A class, you are stating that when you create an A object, it will have the "lst1" attribute. This means that the class A do not have the list, but an object of type A does.

There are two easy fixes for this:

1. Create an static attribute on the A class

```py
class A:
    lst1 = [1,2,3]

class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lst2 = A.lst1
  
  def printLst(self):
    print(self.lst2)

b = B()

b.printLst()
```

2. Create an object of type A and add it to the parameters for B

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lst1 = [1,2,3]

class B:
  def __init__(self, A):
    self.lst2 = A.lst1
  
  def printLst(self):
    print(self.lst2)
a = A()
b = B(a)

b.printLst()
```